# DataGridViewRow.DefaultCellStyle Formatting

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcellstyle

I have this code attached on `RowValidating` event of a `DataGridView`:

```
private void dgvSrc_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;

    if (dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["fullPath"].Value.ToString().Equals("none"))
        dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    else
        dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
}
```

This works but not automatically, you need to focus or click first then select another row to see if its `ForeColor` is changed as red. I tried using `Update` and `Refresh` that does not automatically format the specific row. How can I fix this?

Comment: you should be subscribing to the `CellFormatting` event of the grid and then set the style

Answer (score 1):

Use the `CellFormatting` event of the `DataGridView`

```
dgv.CellFormatting += dgv_CellFormatting
```

Handle it like

```
void dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if(dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["fullPath"].Value.ToString().Equals("none"))
      dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    else
      dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
}
```

Comment: Found this useful but looping through all the rows after loading the data then using the conditions above seems faster on loading. Thanks anyway

Comment: @nathan742 "Thank you anyway" As the question was asked, @ V4Vendetta probably give you the best answer. (I was starting to write the same, he beat me from a few seconds).
"Looping through all the rows after loading the data" is a possible solution but it supposes that values the Grid is readonly. In your question you wrote "This works but not automatically,". I don't understand your comment "Man".

Comment: @Chris i guess what he means by automatically is it sets it only once when the loop is run and not at al times when the value might change

Comment: Yep, @V4Vendetta is right. That's what I did and what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

You are subscribing to the wrong event. I think, you need this one: [CellValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You may do it in your dgv RowPrePaint event ..

```
Private void dgvSrc_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;

if (dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["fullPath"].Value.ToString().Equals("none"))
    dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
else
    dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
}
```